# Why is Java JRE running on my computer?

Tags: windows, java

I have noticed that Java JRE is running on my computer. This even if there is seemingly no program that needs Java support. The questions are:

How can I find out if there are any active (or inactive) programs using Java and will `java.exe` keep running even though all programs requiring Java support is closed?

I tried to run:

```
wmic process where processid=<pid> get commandline
```

In the command prompt (with the correct id of course), but that led me to a PeerTVClient.jar which I guess is the actual Java jar file that is used and not the application that is run by `java.exe`. I find this mysterious and would gladly appreciate some help here.

**EDIT**
I have learned that my earliest assumption must be wrong. Obviously Peer2View Client is run on my computer; I am not sure where it comes from though, only that an .ini file was created 34 minutes after I installed jre7 32-bit... I will vote to close this question for reason: unclear what I am asking for since the answer is Java is run since Peer2View Client is run.

Answer (score 0):

Java JRE Runs when you start a program which uses JAVA. I am a Java developer; I use Eclipse so when I start it, the Java libraries run. But if you want to quit it then simply go to the TASK MANAGER --> Processes --> Select that --> End Process.

What I think it's running all of the time is that because if you ran one application and already it took time to load; then if you run another Java application it won't take time because it happened with me.